# Importing AspectJ in Eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm learning **spring framework** using eclipse IDE. I'm trying to code aspectJ programme but when I import aspectJ it gives error, 
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***aspect-1.9.1.jar*** is an installer for AspectJ, not a library you can directly use in Eclipse. Still you are trying to use it as such in your project. You have to execute it from a console with elevated (admin) rights like this:

```
java -jar aspectj-1.9.1.jar
```

Then follow the installation instructions. After successful installation there will be a ***lib*** folder where you can find the AspectJ runtime ***aspectjrt.jar***. What exactly you need to configure in your IDE depends on your use case:

- Spring AOP or AspectJ?
- If AspectJ, do you use load-time weaving or compile-time weaving?

I would assume for starters you only want to use Spring AOP. How to do that is really out of scope of this answer. But I think for Eclipse it would help to install [AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT)](https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) in any case.

Maybe next time you start reading manuals or using your favourite search engine first before asking questions like this one on SO. I only answered because it was so easy to spot.